# Is it possible to make a label with a while loop?

Tags: loops, kotlin

In the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html) I can see an usage of labels using `for` :

```
loop@ for (i in 1..100) {
    for (j in 1..100) {
        if (...) break@loop
    }
}
```

But it is possible to make a label with a `while` / `do...while` loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course!

```
label@ while (true) {
    continue@label
}

label@ do {
    continue@label
} while (true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can similarly use break with label in while:

```
whileloop@ while (true) {
    for (j in 1..100) {
        print(j)
        if (j == 10) break@whileloop
```